# How to use EasyMock expect

Tags: java, easymock

The expect doesn't seem to work for me:

```
    package com.jjs.caf.library.client.drafting;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.jjs.caf.library.client.CustomerManager;
import com.jjs.caf.library.client.UserBookLimiter;

public class DraftTest {

    UserBookLimiter userBookLimiter;
    int expected = 5;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        userBookLimiter = EasyMock.createMock(UserBookLimiter.class);
        EasyMock.expect(userBookLimiter.getMaxNumberOfBooksAllowed()).andReturn(5);
    }

    @Test
    public final void test() {
        assertEquals(expected, userBookLimiter.getMaxNumberOfBooksAllowed());
    }

}
```

It's supposed to be 5, but I'm getting 0 as if the expect wouldn't be there at all...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, after analysing I finally got it to work by adding `EasyMock.replay(userBookLimiter);`

So the setup method looks like this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    userBookLimiter = EasyMock.createMock(UserBookLimiter.class);
    EasyMock.expect(userBookLimiter.getMaxNumberOfBooksAllowed()).andReturn(5);
    EasyMock.replay(userBookLimiter);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to call the `replay` method on your mock object, so that it starts returning what you configured it to.

Comment: As an additional note: if DraftTest is a class instead of an interface, you have to use org.easymock.classextension.EasyMock.*