# Mock method as parameter another method

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

I have got a problem with testing how many times concrete methods (IFunction in the Operation instance) is invoked.

According to:

1. http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-annotations
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-easymock/
3. [How to use EasyMock expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052445/how-to-use-easymock-expect)

I wrote something as:

```
class Operation{
   public double[] calculateSth(IFunction function, int [] t){
      for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i+=1)
          function(t, new int[]{1,2,3});

   return new double[]{1,2,3};
   }

}

interface IFunction{
   double f(int[] a, int[]b);
}

class ConcreteF implements IFunction{
   double f(int[]a, int[]b){
       return 5;
   }
}
```

And my test class:
    @TestSubject
    Operation op;

```
@Mock
IFunction function;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Sth{
    op=new Operation();
    function = EasyMock.createMock(IFunction.class);
}

@Test
public void howManyTimes(){


    EasyMock.expect(function.f(EasyMock.notNull(), EasyMock.notNull())
                   )
    .andReturn((double)EasyMock.anyDouble()).times(3);


    EasyMock.replay(function);

    op.calculateSth(function, new double[]{0,0,0});

    //verify
    EasyMock.verify(function);

}
```

Result:
        java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.easymock.internal.Injector.injectMocks(Injector.java:80)
at org.easymock.EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(EasyMockSupport.java:624)
at org.easymock.EasyMockRunner.withBefores(EasyMockRunner.java:50)
```

It's my first time using easymock and i don't know how to fix it ;/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer this question without going into the details of whether the original method does anything useful (the code doesn't even compile anyway), let alone the test method.

`@TestSubject Operation op;`

This line is a suspect. I realize that you are instantiating it in the `@Before` annotated `setUp` method, but it looks like the `Easymock` tries to inject the mocks (the ones annotated with `@Mock`) before it does anything (and understandably so) and blows up since the reference is `null` at that point.

The annotation support introduced in `v3.2` is also seen as a way to eliminate the need for `setUp` method. But you seem to be mixing both and using it wrongly. Choose one or the other - I'd recommend you to use the annotations.

Quoting the `Easymock` [user guide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-annotations) (this user guide is as good as it can ever be, so be sure read this up before using the library),

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class) 
public class ExampleTest {

  @TestSubject 
  private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(); // 2 

  @Mock 
  private Collaborator mock; // 1 

  @Test 
  public void testRemoveNonExistingDocument() { 
    replay(mock); 
    classUnderTest.removeDocument("Does not exist"); 
  } 
}
```

> The `mock` is instantiated by the runner at step 1. It is then set by
>   the runner, to the `listener` field on step 2. The `setUp` method can be
>   removed since all the initialization was done by the runner.